# Jinja2 extensions - get the value of variable passed to extension

Tags: python, jinja2

So I have a Jinja2 extension. Basically follows the parser logic, except that I need to get a value from the parsed args being passed in.

For instance, if I have an extension called loadfile, and pass it a variable:

`{% loadfile "file.txt" %}`

when I grab the argument through `parser.parse_expression()` I get a `node.Const` variable that has a `.value` argument - and I can get the name `file.txt` no problem.

However...

```
{% set filename = "file.txt" %}
{% loadfile filename %}
```

causes me issues. The parser gives me a `node.Name` expr node, which neither responds to `.value` or the `as_const(...)` call that all other nodes respond to.

I can't figure out how to evaluate the value of the `node.Name` node I'm getting from parsing the arguments, and thus cannot get the name `file.txt`.

Is there a good way to parse argument variables/values in an extension so that I can use them to execute the extention?

Thanks!

Comment: Your `node.Name` looks like this - `Name(name='filename', ctx='load')`? I think it would be evaluated this way: `return nodes.Output([nodes.MarkSafeIfAutoescape(self.call_method('your_method', args))]).set_lineno(lineno)
`, and a method: `def your_method(self, filename):`

Comment: Why do you need an extension. You can use a Python function which returns the content or use include.

Comment: @voscausa the extension does something far more complex, I just simplified the example to clearly illustrate the question.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
def parse(self, parser):
    lineno = parser.stream.next().lineno

    # args will contains filename
    args = [parser.parse_expression()]

    return nodes.Output([
        nodes.MarkSafeIfAutoescape(self.call_method('handle', args))
    ]).set_lineno(lineno)

def handle(self, filename):
    # bla-bla-bla
```

Comment: That gives me an ```AttributeError: 'Environment' object has no attribute 'call'``` but I must be in a template render loop somewhere...

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to why variables aren't evaluated before being passed in to a extension/function.