# Jinj2 Extension - Skip clause if the variable is None

Tags: python, jinja2

### Intention

I'm trying to write a Jinja extension that emulates [Metabase's "optional" clauses](https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/questions/native-editor/sql-parameters#optional-clauses), where an expression between double square brackets `[[ ... ]]` will only be kept if the value of the variable inside it is not `None`

For example (using the example in [the Metabase docs](https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/questions/native-editor/sql-parameters#optional-clauses)), consider the following template:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM products
[[ WHERE category = {{ cat }} ]]
```

If the value of `cat` is `None`, everything inside the `[[ ... ]]` is removed; otherwise the content inside the double square brackets is rendered like normal and only the square brackets themselves are removed like normal Jinja stuff

To keep this simple, we can assume that any pair of double square brackets will have exactly one variable inside them but there can be any number of these double square bracket clauses

### Current (failing) MWE

I've currently implemented 3 things:

1. The `preprocess` method to convert `[[ ... ]]` to `{% optional %} ... {% endoptional %}` so that I can look for the `optional` tag in the implementation
2. The `parse` method to find and adjust the `optional` blocks
3. A custom `filter` method to apply the "if" logic based on the *value* of the variable in the double brackets

Note that the third point is what I've tried following the answers to the following similar questions:

- [Jinja2 extensions - get the value of variable passed to extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21924444/8213085)
- [How to access context variables from the Jinja's Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12139029/8213085)

Although this allows me to get the value of the variable to check whether it's `None`, I now can't get the full clause to render properly if it *isn't* `None` and I can't figure out how to do this correctly -- it just prints out the list of nodes, not a rendered version of them (see next section)

The latest (failing) MWE I have at the moment is:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Any

from jinja2 import nodes, ext, parser

START, END = "[[", "]]"


class OptionalClausesExtension(ext.Extension):
    """
    Jinja2 extension to allow optional clauses in templates.
    """
    tags = {"optional"}

    def preprocess(self, source: str, name: str | None, filename: str | None = None) -> str:
        """
        Preprocess the source by converting ``[[`` and ``]]`` to
        ``{% optional %}`` and ``{% endoptional %}`` for parsing.
        """
        for old, new in [(START, "{% optional %}"), (END, "{% endoptional %}")]:
            source = source.replace(old, new)

        return source

    def parse(self, parser: parser.Parser) -> nodes.Node | list[nodes.Node]:
        """
        Parse the template and return the parsed nodes.
        """
        parser.parse_expression()
        body = parser.parse_statements(["name:endoptional"], drop_needle=True)
        self._body = body  # I'm guessing this is what bypasses the rendering, but I'm not sure what to do otherwise

        # For now, only support *exactly* one variable in the optional clause
        name_args = []
        for output in body:
            name_args.extend(iter(output.find_all(nodes.Name)))
        assert len(name_args) == 1

        return nodes.Output([self.call_method("filter", name_args)])

    def filter(self, name_arg: Any):
        return "" if name_arg is None else self._body
        # return "" if name_arg is None else Template(self._body).render()
```

The commented line beneath `filter` is only to illustrate that I've tried some explicit rendering, but that doesn't work (and doesn't feel right either) and I can't figure out how else to get the `body` into the `filter` function

I don't understand Jinja under the hood so I suspect that this may be an invalid way to extend it, but any help getting this to work would be really appreciated -- or pointing me to some other feature/place that can do something like this instead

### The corresponding test

For reference/clarity, I'm trying to get the following test to pass:

```py
import jinja2
import pytest

import jinja_optional_clauses.main as main


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "raw, var, rendered",
    [
        ["out [[ in {{ var }} ]] out", "thing", "out  in thing  out"],
        ["out [[ in {{ var }} ]] out", None, "out  out"],
    ],
)
def test__render_optional_clause(raw: str, var: str, rendered: str):
    """
    Test that optional clauses are rendered correctly.

    If the variable is not provided, the optional clause should be removed;
    otherwise, the clause should be rendered as normal.
    """
    env = jinja2.Environment(extensions=[main.OptionalClausesExtension])
    template = env.from_string(raw)

    assert template.render(var=var) == rendered
```

At the moment, this passes for the `None` case but for the `thing` case it is still using the unrendered list of nodes (most likely because of the `self._body` attribute):

```
# expected
out  in thing  out

# actual
out [Output(nodes=[TemplateData(data=' in '), Name(name='var', ctx='load'), TemplateData(data=' ')])] out
```